# How to Trigger LinkButton Postback after Confirmation using jQuery UI Dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, webforms, jquery-ui-dialog

I want a LinkButton to popup a jQuery UI dialog that prompts the user to confirm the action. If the user hits OK, then I'd like the action to continue by posting back to the server.

I ended up creating two links: One is regular HTML that invokes my confirmation dialog. And the other is a regular LinkButton server control that is hidden, and that I want to invoke if the user confirms the dialog box.

The two links look like this:

```
<a id="preEnterOperations" href="#">
    Enter Operations
</a>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEnterOperations" runat="server"
    OnClick="lnkEnterOperations_Click" Style="display:none">
    Enter Operations
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And here's my JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#preEnterOperations').on('click',
        function (e) {
            var confirmDialog = $('#enterOperationsConfirmationDialog');
            confirmDialog.dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        confirmDialog.dialog("close");
                        confirmDialog.data('confirmed', '1');
                        $('#<%= lnkEnterOperations.ClientID %>').click();
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        confirmDialog.dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
});
```

Everything seems right. The confirmation dialog pops up as expected. I can see my Ok handler runs if the user hits Ok. But the line `$('#<%= lnkEnterOperations.ClientID %>').click();` doesn't do a thing! I've tried numerous variations on this line and the effect is always the same: nothing.

Can anyone help me see how I can execute a LinkButton postback if the user confirms the dialog box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the following line:

```
$('#<%= lnkEnterOperations.ClientID %>').click();
```

With:

```
__doPostBack('<%= lnkEnterOperations.UniqueID %>', '');
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
                Ok: function () {
                    confirmDialog.dialog("close");
                    confirmDialog.data('confirmed', '1');
                    $('#<%= lnkEnterOperations.ClientID %>').click(function(){
                         __doPostBack('<%= lnkEnterOperations.UniqueID %>', '');
                    });
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    confirmDialog.dialog("close");
                }
```

May be this can help.

Comment: What does this do? It looks like it creates a new click handler each time through. But the handler won't be called until the user clicks it again. And server controls already have their own handler. Is this an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace "**$('#<%= lnkEnterOperations.ClientID %>').click();**" 
with **<%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lnkEnterOperations, "") %>**